# Retrieving chat messages

Tags: php, sql, foreach

I'm trying to get chat messages from my phpmyadmin database (it has 2 messages in it), but there is something wrong with my query. Here it is:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM chat WHERE (user_from='". $_SESSION['username'] ."' AND user_to='". $result['username'] ."') OR (user_from='". $result['username'] ."' AND user_to='". $_SESSION['username'] ."') ORDER BY id DESC";
$chatlog = $db->query($query);
$message = $chatlog->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

When running this code: `echo $message['message'];`
only the first message shows up, I have also tried using foreach, but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: when changing ORDER BY id DESC to ASC only the second message shows up

Comment: [`fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) only fetches one row (the first row) of the query. You may want to use a loop to fetch all the rows into an array. Alternatively, you may be able to use [`fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) [if your system supports it](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-all-mysqlnd).

Comment: For clarity: when I said "the first row", I was referring only to your specific context. `fetch_array` fetches the *next* row of the query, identified by the position of the result pointer. In your case, that's the first row.

Answer (score 2):

You only get back one message because thats what `fetch_array` does - it gets the next record as an array.

If you want to get multiple records, you'll need to loop over the rows and call `fetch_array` for each row:

```
while ($message = $chatlog->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
   $messages[] = $message;
}
```

Also, used parameterized queries or [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to save yourself from SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot guys, it worked when using fetch_all here is my code now:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM chat WHERE (user_from='". $_SESSION['username'] ."' AND user_to='". $result['username'] ."') OR (user_from='". $result['username'] ."' AND user_to='". $_SESSION['username'] ."') ORDER BY id DESC";
$chatlog = $db->query($query);
$message = $chatlog->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach ($message as $chat) {
echo $chat['message'];
}
```

Comment: Great! Please note that ([according to php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-all-mysqlnd)) `fetch_all` "may consume more memory", requires "a looping construct that will further impact performance", and "should only be used in those situations where the fetched result set will be sent to another layer for processing". Make of that what you will.